# Matlab won't change fit's limits

Tags: matlab, data-fitting

I am using Matlab to fit some data in 2 coordinates (x,y) with a poly1 curve.

The problem is that I can't find a way to make the fitting line longer.

I need it from (180, 930) to (191, 944), but instead Matlab just draw the fitting line near the data, which is between those two coordinates.

Is there some argument to the fit command (or some preferences in the cftool) that can help me out?

Moreover, I've tried the "Adjust axes limits" option in the cftool, but it didn't help at all.

I've searched through the already asked questions, but I haven't found anything related to this.
I'm new to this program, therefore I'm sorry if this is a stupid question
Thanks in advance,
Giovanni

EDIT:
The code for the first image is:

```
[FitUp,goodnessUP] = fit(AKaterMatrix1msDX(:,1),AKaterMatrix1msDX(:,2),'poly1')
[FitDown,goodnessDOWN] = fit(AKaterMatrix1msDX(:,1),AKaterMatrix1msDX(:,3),'poly1')
plot(FitUp,'b')
hold on
plot(FitDown,'b')
hold on
errorbar(AKaterMatrix1msDX(:,1),AKaterMatrix1msDX(:,2),AKaterMatrix1msDX(:,4),'--r')
hold on
errorbar(AKaterMatrix1msDX(:,1),AKaterMatrix1msDX(:,3),AKaterMatrix1msDX(:,4),'--r')
```

The code for the second is:

```
[FitUp,goodnessUP] = fit(AKaterMatrix1msDX(:,1),AKaterMatrix1msDX(:,2),'poly1')
[FitDown,goodnessDOWN] = fit(AKaterMatrix1msDX(:,1),AKaterMatrix1msDX(:,3),'poly1')
plot(FitDown,'b')
hold on
plot(FitUp,'b')
hold on
errorbar(AKaterMatrix1msDX(:,1),AKaterMatrix1msDX(:,2),AKaterMatrix1msDX(:,4),'--r')
hold on
errorbar(AKaterMatrix1msDX(:,1),AKaterMatrix1msDX(:,3),AKaterMatrix1msDX(:,4),'--r')
```

Here you can find the two fits, it appears that the first fit is not cropped, while the second after the `hold on` is:
https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B749BCu7mnZHaEhITUZ1YzdfVDA/edit?usp=sharing
https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B749BCu7mnZHeDVTOGRuSkktUmc/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Please add code to your question.

Comment: I have added the code and the fits' images to clarify my question.

Comment: I can't comment on the use of 'fit', although if you're just fitting a simple polynomial, `polyfit` and `polyeval` may be better. Once you have your fitted polynomial, you can evaluate it over any grid you want. Also, the `hold` function is a toggle. Only the first one is necessary (and should probably be followed by a `hold off` after the last errorbar command).

Comment: That is a brilliant idea, thank you. Just one more question. The informations about the goodness of the fit (SSE, R-squared...) are the same that cftool or the fit command give me? If not, how can I obtain them?

Comment: Thanks @craigim, if you or someone else posts an answer I can mark the question as answered. How can I give you points if you only commented?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to be careful when and how you set the hold. First make some dummy data

```
AKaterMatrix1msDX(:, 1) = 185:189;
AKaterMatrix1msDX(:, 2) = 2*rand(5, 1)+933;
AKaterMatrix1msDX(:, 3) = 2*rand(5, 1)+940;
AKaterMatrix1msDX(:, 4) = 2*rand(5, 1);
```

Next, and this is the key part, set the axis to be what you want and turn hold on

```
figure
axis([180, 191, 930, 944]);
hold on
```

This do exactly what you did

```
[FitUp,goodnessUP] = fit(AKaterMatrix1msDX(:,1),AKaterMatrix1msDX(:,2),'poly1')
[FitDown,goodnessDOWN] = fit(AKaterMatrix1msDX(:,1),AKaterMatrix1msDX(:,3),'poly1')
plot(FitUp,'b')
hold on
plot(FitDown,'b')
hold on
errorbar(AKaterMatrix1msDX(:,1),AKaterMatrix1msDX(:,2),AKaterMatrix1msDX(:,4),'--r')
hold on
errorbar(AKaterMatrix1msDX(:,1),AKaterMatrix1msDX(:,3),AKaterMatrix1msDX(:,4),'--r')
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need a lot of fit statistics, `polyfit` followed by `polyval` can give you your fit:

```
X = AKaterMatrix1msDX(:,1);
Y = AKaterMatrix1msDX(:,2);
dY = AKaterMatrix1msDX(:,4);
[a,S] = polyfit(X,Y)
extraPlotRange = 10;
newX = linspace(min(X)-extraPlotRange,max(X)+extraPlotRange,100);

[fitY,delta] = polyval(a,newX);

plot(X,Y)
hold on
plot(newX,fitY)
plot(newX,fitY+delta,':b')
plot(newX,fitY-delta,':b')
errorbar(X,Y,dY,'--r')
hold off
```

This will not, unfortunately, give you the same goodness of fit statistics that you might need, only the confidence intervals of the fit.

The other option, if you want to stay with `fit`, would be to get the fit coefficients using [`coeffvalues`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/curvefit/coeffvalues.html). Those fit coefficients would be the same as you get from `polyfit`.

```
aUp = coeffvalues(FitUp);
aDown = coeffValues(FitDown);

fitYup = polyval(aUp,newX);
fitYdown = polyval(aDown,newX);
```

etc.